# Facebook Graph API how to get user ID who likes or comments on a post of a Facebook Page

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I have written a PHP script where Facebook Graph API is integrated. I want to get the list of user IDs who like or comment on posts of my Facebook Page.
I have called this API end point. It returns only comment message and no of likes but doesn't return user ID.

I called these endpoints -

```
$endPointFormat = 'https://graph.facebook.com/{object-id}/comments?access_token={access-token}';
```

```
$endpointFormat = 'https://graph.facebook.com/{object-id}?fields=likes.summary(true)&access_token={access-token}';
```

It returns only comment message and no of likes but doesn't return user ID. I want to get the list of user IDs. How can I get ID of users?

[image]